# Windows style in Windowbuilder

Tags: java, windows, export, windowbuilder

Hey I coded a calculator. In the design Tab I set it to Windows but wehn I export it, its the nasty "Metal" theme. And it dosnt look like i designed it. Sincerely Jonathan

[The Eclipse View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r7O7.jpg)

[When I export it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Tlw.jpg)

Comment: You do need to set the desired Look&Feel within the application itself. If one isn't provided and the application is run in Windows then it **should** default to Windows L&F. There are two common Windows L&F's, `Windows` and `Windows Classic`.

Comment: If you found a solution please create an answer instead of editing the question to indicate it.

Comment: "it dosnt look like i designed it" Sure does. It has the same typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

First you need to go to: Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder > Swing > LookAndFeel

Then you tick Windows > Apply & Close

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                YourFrame frame = new YourFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```